# How to burn the iso file window in disc?

Tags: kali-linux, disk, burning

This is my PC/OS detail

[image: This is my PC/OS detail]

I recently downloaded a **90 days trial version** of Windows.

My question is, when I right clicked to burn disc, I did't get any option like 'Burn to disc'.
How to burn the ISO to disc?

Comment: wodim/cdrecord and it's various graphical frontends like k3b.

Answer (score 0):

you can use brasero. it has easy to use GUI.

```
apt install brasero
```

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: as it said, another apt process is running. you have to close it first